# Change of one field in the html table, changes a specific element inside that table. Not in other tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I know that the practice is that every element has a unique id. I am curious about this case: I have a table (let's call it table1) that has many functions connecting its cells in various ways (ex: editing one cell changes other cells accordingly). Now, I need to have another table (let's call it table2), that will have exact same functions between its cells.
I would like to avoid changing the ids in the table2, and then copy pasting the js functions for the table1 and apply them for the ids from the table2.
The easiest thing for me would be to just copy-paste this table1 (so the cells in the table1 and table2 will have same ids), and adapt the js functions to make sure that whenever a change in table1 happens - only table1 is affected, and not cells in table2, and vice versa.

Example:

```
$('body').on('keyup', "input[id^='sub_']", function() {
$("[id^='top_']").val(5);
}
```

Now, I suppose if I have an id that begins with "top_" in both tables that the change in table1 will also change the value of the field "top_" in table2.
How can I make sure to avoid this?
I was thinking to do something like this:

```
$(this).closest("input[id^='top_']");
```

But this is not working, the values are changed in both tables... Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: your problem is very high level and not getting what exact operation you want to perform. can you share working jsfiddle or code snippet that recreates your problem

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar thanks for replying. I can't share any code unfortunately, but the main point is that I have two tables that are identical in structure and in ids. When I change value in one cell in table1 it triggers the function that changes some other field in table1. But because I have same ids in table1 and table2 this change in table1 changes values in table2, too. And I don't want that change in table2 to happen...I understand that it's quit tricky to get this, and I thank you again for trying...

Comment: simple and short way is give a class name and based on that you can achieve this things

Comment: @CoolJK Thanks for commenting, but I don't think you understood the problem. Introducing class name wouldn't solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet:

```
$(this).closest("table").find("input[id^='top_']");
```

This will make sure the changes are made only within the table where the event occurred.

**EDIT**
Here is a small example that you can modify for your needs if you don't want to provide your HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/fjh0v6m4/10/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's still affecting both tables.

Comment: Are the tables nested?

Comment: They are not nested, they have multiple bodies, though. Thank you for your example, I'll try to adapt it for my case.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you table has multiple <tbody> tags, right? The fields whose values should not change between tables are not but any chance in the same table but in a different <tbody> tag?

Comment: Yes, more concretely, my table has multiple <tbody> tags. Field that needs to be changed by the change of the other field is not in the same <tbody> as the field that is changed. I love this sentence. xD

Comment: And the fields that should NOT be changed are in completely different table, not just a different <tbody>, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
$('#sameid')[0].dosomething()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.